# Correct way to copy Swift project without altering old project?

Tags: swift

I was wondering if there was a correct way to make a copy of a Swift project?

I realised that when I want to make a copy of a project (so that I can have a backup working copy when I continue with my project and I make a mistake) and I use that copy; the copy alters the build folder of my original file. Not only that but if I re-name classes or change IBLabels/IBOutlets, and although the change isn't reflected in the original code; when I compile the original file there will an error associated to an undefined class or the `xib` file would be changed which would also throw an error. At the start the original file compiled, but after working on the copy of the original file and running into an error. The original file also wouldn't compile, any ideas on why this happens? And how to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use version control? i.e. git? And if you use git you should use [git flow](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Just copy the whole folder from a to b!

---

IF you used absolute paths in your xcode project though .. bad for you :/ your project references the original files no matter what

what **you can try** is fixing the project.pbxproj xml file manually. this is doable but not supported by xcode really :/

---

IMHO if a copy isn't enough because you messed up the project with absolute paths, **readd all files MANUALLY** and make sure all is relative to the project location

Comment: I copy the whole folder as well but it still changes my original file :(

Comment: SURE IT DOES -- it might be a bit brief.. low quality even -- but it is a valid answer

Comment: @MayankJain I even added additional info

Answer (score 0):

Though @Daij-Djan's answer is correct you need to watch for added files with relative paths. So what I do for a backup is to use git. That works better than any backup.

If you really want a copy, just copy the folder with the project with CMD-D which creates a `<folder> Copy` (or whatever is your localization). You can rename the copy, but leave the contents untouched. Also do leave it in the same folder as the original one to avoid conflicts with relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Just zip your current project & extract it inside your new project folder & enjoy....